# .NET 7 Windows Services : Start with powershell with environment variable

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell, windows-services

I have a problem with my Windows Services created in .NET 7.
When the project is installed on the computer, we need to create 3 windows services :

- One for Development environment
- One for Integration environment
- One for PreProd environment

In .NET 7, the Windows service application search its environment in this variable : DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT

So in my powershell script, I use this :

```
$Env:DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
Start-Service -Name "NameOfMyService"
```

And this doesn't work. The service starts but it doesn't care about the environment variable

I tried to install the service like this :

```
$Env:DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
$parameters = @{
    Name = "test",
    BinaryPathName = "",
    ...
}
New-Service @parameters
```

But this doesn't work too :(

How can I install or start a windows service with an environment configuration ?

This is mandatory because the customer we work with has only one server with all environment in it...

Comment: You will have to [persist the env var's state](https://superuser.com/questions/1729958/how-do-i-permanently-set-a-system-variable-system-environmentsetenvironment) in the system.

Comment: That's because `New-Service` won't spawn a process from your PowerShell process (and hence your shell's env vars are not propagated).

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of you. With [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT', $environment, 'Machine') the service was successfully installed and executed

Comment: Me and I are very glad we could help you 